# cognos 8 - how to get a set of more sets

Tags: sql, cognos

I have created a report , and faced some problem
i have a course reference number that have many sections 
and have meeting type
the course reference number may have an Exam and Class 
for example

```
course reference Number    Meeting type 
12345                       class   
12345                       Exam
```

and some courses reference number doesn't have at all exam
only class

how to retrieve and extract only the reference number that doesn't have exam at all ..

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume if there is just one [Meeting Type] that it is "Class", and two would be "Class", "Exam"? If so, create a data item which is count([Meeting Type]). Next, create a summary filter where count([Meeting Type]) = 1

If a course can have one [Meeting Type]  that is either "Class" or "Exam", I would do through two queries. It can't be done in just one query (without the use of custom SQL). Conceptually, first query is Courses of type "Exam". Second query is all Courses. Connect them using the "Except" operator in the Toolbox.